# PHP syntax for if ( ! class_exists ...)

Tags: php, syntax, php-7

where i can find documentation on syntax :

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'myClass', false ) ) :
  class myClass {   }
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

On PHP's official documentation website?

[class_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists)

[if](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.if.php)